# T1 and T2 registry keys under wireless network adapter's settings?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-registry

Under local machine\tcpip\params\interfaces. Do they even do anything? For reference its possible values are in 0x{8 digit hex} format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are timers T1 and T2 from the DHCP protocol. T1 is when your DHCP client should first try to renew your lease and T2 is when it should try again if it failed at T1. T2 is usually about 7/8ths of the way to when your lease expires. T1 is usually half of the lease time; that is, your DHCP client is supposed to start trying to renew your lease when half the lease time is used up.

More info from Microsoft TechNet:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978471.aspx